# Extjs 5 how to store user detail after login, and use it for data binding in a ViewModel

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs5

I am new to extjs 5. Been spending alot of  time trying to learn it, and have a hard time understanding some things.

I have been able to create an authentication system, but the problem im having is where to store the user object. After reading some docs and other answers here on SO, these where the strategies i came up with

Authenticate user and retrieve user data, then :-

- **Create a Model Instance with user data and store it in a global variable :**
  Problem is how do i add this to a viewmodel so that i can data bind its fields to a view. For example
  bind User Name to text of a button.
- **Create a model link  in the viewModel:**
  The problem with this is, How do i pass in the model Id so that i can retrieve the user from the server.
- **Store the user data in a global variable, then in view controller , access viewModel memory store proxy, then add the data to the store, then load the store.**
  Problem is when i do it this way I still cant access the data in my view for data binding.

Please see snipets  below :-

## Scenario 1

### Application.js

```js
Ext.define('Wilma.Application', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

requires: [
    "Wilma.DirectAPI",
    'Wilma.view.login.Login'
],    
name: 'Wilma',

views: [
    'Wilma.view.MyViewport'
],

stores: [
    // TODO: add stores here
],
enableQuickTips: true,

launch: function() {
     ExtRemote.HWLogin.loginStatus('', function(result, event){
        if(result.success){
            console.log('i was called' + result.data);
            //Global variable
            Wilma.app.LoggedInUser =  Ext.create(Wilma.model.User, result.data.user);
            console.log(Wilma.app.LoggedInUser);
            Ext.widget('mainviewport');
           }
          else {
               Ext.widget('login');
           }

        }
     });
 });
```

### ViewModel

```js
Ext.define('Wilma.view.header.usermenu.UsermenuModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.usermenu',
    requires: [
        'Wilma.store.Users',
        'Wilma.model.User'
    ],

    // ???????????????
    // ???????????????
    // What do i do here
});
```

## Scenario 2

### App.js

Relevant part:

```js
launch: function() {
     ExtRemote.HWLogin.loginStatus('', function(result, event){
        if(result.success){
            console.log('i was called' + result.data);
            //Global variable
            Wilma.app.LoggedInUser =  Ext.create(Wilma.model.User, result.data.user);
                     //OR
            //Wilma.app.LoggedInUser = result.data.user

            console.log(Wilma.app.LoggedInUser);
            Ext.widget('mainviewport');
           }
          else {
               Ext.widget('login');
           }

        }
     });
```

### ViewModel

```js
links: {
    loggedinuser:{
        reference: 'user',
        id: Wilma.app.LoggedInUser.get('_id')
    }
}
```

## Scenario 3

### ViewController

```js
Ext.define('Wilma.view.header.usermenu.UsermenuController', {
extend: 'Wilma.controller.BaseViewController',
alias: 'controller.usermenu',

onbeforerender: function(button, eOpts) {
    var userstore = this.getViewModel().getStore('usermenu');
        userstore.getProxy().data = Wilma.app.LoggedInUser;
        userstore.load();
    //userstore.add(Wilma.app.LoggedInUser);

}
});
```

### ViewModel

```js
Ext.define('Wilma.view.header.usermenu.UsermenuModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.usermenu',
requires: [
    'Wilma.store.Users',
    'Wilma.model.User'
],


stores: {
    usermenu: {
        model: 'Wilma.model.User',
        proxy:{
            type: 'memory'
        },
        reader: {
            type:'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
            //messageProperty:'message'
        },
        autoLoad:false

      }
    }
});
```

Please, I have been stuck on this for far too long. Please need help?

Let me summarize:

What I want to do is authenticate a user, get user details and store it somewhere databind to the user data in a viewModel and a view (in this case button text)

Thank you

Comment: I believe this does what you need (grab information form a store and saves it to the viewModel): http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-child-session

Comment: Thank you, But im sorry, that doesnt help me. In most of these examples, they deal with grids and stores. what if i just want one record, or get a specific record without using a grid. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any view controller where the view has a view model, or a component that has a view model assigned, you can use `getViewModel()`. So:

```js
Ext.define('MainViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main'
});
```

```js
Ext.define('MainViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',

    launch: function() {
        ExtRemote.HWLogin.loginStatus('', function(result, event) {
            if(result.success){
                this.getViewModel().set('currentUser',
                    Ext.create('User', result.data.user));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```js
Ext.define('MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    viewModel: 'main',

    bind: { title: '{currentUser.username}' }
});
```

After getting the login result, the currentUser is set on the view model and it becomes available for use in the view.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I also was not sure about doing this in the view controller.